# How to pass array values from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP array here:

```
$newArray = array(4,27,34,52,54,59,61,68,78,82,85,87,91,93,100);
```

I want this PHP array to be passed on to my JavaScript code to make my 'data' variable in my JavaScript the same as the array I declared on my PHP script. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    data:  [4,27,34,52,54,59,61,68,78,82,85,87,91,93,100];

});
</script>
```

My idea is just embed the $newArray directly like this:

```
data: <?php $newArray ?>
```

But it doesn't work. How would I do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `data: <?php echo json_encode($newArray) ?>`

Comment: @MLeFevre Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing

```
data: <?php $newArray ?>
```

wouldn't output the contents of $newArray, you'd still need to output as well, by doing either

```
echo $newArray
print $newArray
```

(Try that and you'll get a different error ;)) But even then, it won't be in the format that you want, so you'll want to use `json_encode` encode on it to format in a way that javascript can read it, like so

```
data: <?php echo json_encode($newArray) ?>;
```

Comment: You would need to first flatten the array, (like you did with the json_encode) you can't simply echo/print an array

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's built in json_encode() function like this:

```
$array = array("item_1" => 1, "item_2"=> 2);
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Then pass that array to your JavaScript (via AJAX or some other method) and decode with the jQuery function $.parseJSON() like this:

```
$(function(){
    var json = $.parseJSON(passedFromPHP);
});
```

This will give you a JSON object that you can manipulate with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
data: [<?php echo implode(',', $newArray); ?>];
```